# Raspberry Pi 4 wont connect to 2.4ghz WiFi

Tags: wifi, pi-4, connection

I am attempting to connect to my RPI 4 to a 2.4GHz wifi signal, but it doesn't connect or provide any error messages. Instead it just remains disconnected. Oddly enough, connecting to any 5GHz signal works. I've noticed this behavior on multiple wifi networks. Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the channel range to 2.4GHz by [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103899/44221).

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us what error messages you get but you can try to restrict the connection to specific frequencies. In `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` add a line with frequencies you want to use, for example (but use your own settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=`):

```
cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
#freq_list=5170 5180 5190 5200 5210 5220 5230 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="verySecretPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    mode=RSN WPA
}
```