# How do I know that a Dual-Band USB WiFi dongle will work on Raspbian or other Linux distrobution?

Tags: wifi, usb, hardware, kernel, driver

How do I know if a Dual band USB WiFi dongle will work on a Raspberry Pi running Linux?
I know that Linux must have a driver that supports the wifi chipset used in the dongle. But with the number of WiFi dongles available how do you choose?

Comment: Have you thought about buying from a reputable supplier such as The Pi Hut, Pimoroni, Adafruit, Element 14, RS Components etc? You may need a powered usb hub though - Ralink RT5572 devices can suck power link nothing else (other than HDDs)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a detailed list of supported [RPi USB Wi-Fi Adapters](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters).

If you have the USB/WiFi dongle available you can look at its valid interface combinations with `iw list`. For example on a RPi 4B you will find:

```
--- snip ---
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
       total <= 4, #channels <= 1
--- snip ---
```

Here you will find how much channels are supported by a particular interface combination. For a more detailed discussion of this issue you can look at [Can RPi4 run simultaneously on dual band (WiFi 2.4GHz / 5GHz)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103899/79866).

Answer (score 2):

You can check on [wiki.kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers) for supported **Drivers** and his supported **PHY modes** : `A/B/G/N/AC`

- `802.11 B/G` work on `2.4GHz Band` and `802.11 A/AC` work on `5Ghz Band` so it's Dual Band.
- `802.11 N` have : `single-band` 2.4 GHz equipment (the oldest), `dual-band` adapters (2.4 GHz or 5 GHz) or `dual-radio`: 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz simultaneously.

I'm confuse with `802.11n` for my answer. But I think if 802.11n is in the supported PHY modes, 2.4GHz and 5GHz Bands should be supported by the driver.